# Adding 'lat' and 'lng' to existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

I have an array for a polygon and it isn't formatted correctly for google maps API.  It's a simple javascript solution I'm sure, but I'm new to JS so wondering if you can tell me what I have wrong in the code below.

I know I'm close with the code below.

```
let path = [[59.523341487842316, -9.193736158410616],
           [59.535126839526605, -9.175282560388155],
           [59.529311101819324, -9.147215925256319],
           [59.51395167489177, -9.158202253381319],
           [59.51139973569412, -9.190560422936983],
           [59.521402457849575, -9.174424253503389],
           [59.50946015912328, -9.207211576501436]];    

path.map ( e => ({lat: e[0], lng: e[1]}) )                                                         
console.log(path);

// Construct the polygon.
var geoFences = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: path,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.35
});
```

You can see I'm setting path variable to what I have in terms of x,y coordinates and using .map to try and add proper json and lat lng text. I need the output to look like this:

```
path = [
    {lat: 59.523341487842316, lng: -7.193736158410616},
    {lat: 59.535126839526605, lng: -7.175282560388155}
    /* etc.. */
];
```

Comment: `path = path.map ( e => ({lat: e[0], lng: e[1]}) )`

Comment: wow, i was missing that... thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.map` do not modify exist array, it return a mapped array instead. You should assign the result to a variable.

---

`path = path.map ( e => ({lat: e[0], lng: e[1]}) )`

Answer (score 0):

I would create an empty array an add the objects to it

```
let pathObj = []
path.map( e => pathObj = {lat: e[0], lng: e[1]} )
```